# should I insert a copyright notice into my Kindle Direct Publishing Vella publication?

Tags: publishing, copyright, self-publishing, kindle

Is it a good idea to have a copyright notice at the beginning or end of each episode, or in my Vella story's Description section?

I'm thinking maybe:
"COPYRIGHT 2022 BY  ALL RIGHTS RESERVED"

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary to include a copyright notice in your Kindle Direct Publishing Vella publication, but doing so can help to deter potential infringers and establish your ownership of the work. You can include a copyright notice in the beginning, end, or Description section of each episode, or in your Vella story's Description section.